# 3G Modem sim on my Nexus S

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, 4.1-jelly-bean, data-connection, wifi-tethering

I have a 3G modem, and have tried it's sim card in a couple different modens with success.

However, I tried to put in on my Nexus S and use wifi tether, but it didn't work - although it seemed to have network signal, the data was not working. My guess was it misses the authentication part (for each different modem I tried, I had to add the operator's credentials).

I was wondering how do I configure my smartphone so it would act like a modem?

I have a `Nexus S` with Android 4.1.1

Comment: **4.1.x** would be *Jelly Bean*, not *Ice Cream Sandwich*.

Comment: Are you asking how to *normally* setup an Android device as a WiFi hot-spot ("tethering"), **OR** how to achieve this with the SIM card you using?

Comment: I want to do this with the data-only sim card.